# Response from before_request

Tags: python, response, bottle

In my app I am trying to check if user is authorised to access the resource, for example when user requests to url *api/proxy*.

I use before_request to call checking function

```
 @hook('before_request') 
 def check_permission():
     securityService = SecurityService(db=db)
     try:
         securityService.check_access_permission(request)
     except Exception as e:
        print("excepting")
        return json.dumps({'Error': str(e)})
        // stop execution here
```

The functionality of access checking is tested, I raise exception when access is not granted. Even in server log I can see "excepting". Return statement dont stop the execution process.

But the code dont stop execution and continues to proxy_get function

```
@get('/api/proxy')
def proxy_get():
    response = proxyService.get()
    return json.dumps({"Response" : response})
```

Is there any way to stop request handling in before_request function, or am I just messing something up? Whats the proper solution?

How do I set status code to that response? 
I tried

```
response.status_code(401)
```

but it didnt work. I was getting error TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Answer (score 1):

You should probably create a controller for *Access denied* and then modify the **request** to redirect to that controller. So, your code would look something like this:

```
@hook('before_request') 
def check_permission():
    securityService = SecurityService(db=db)
    try:
        securityService.check_access_permission(request)
    except Exception as e:
       request.environ['PATH_INFO'] = '/error_401'

@route('/error_401')
    response.body = json.dumps({'Error': str(e)}
    response.status = 401
    return response
```

I have actually never used Bottle, so this might not the best way of doing it but it worked with simple test code.